# Polyline to Point using Rust - shapefile

Tags: rust, shapefile

With the code below I can create a Polyline and write it to a shape file. But I would also like to read a shape file of type Polyline and convert the Point to get x: f64 and y: f64.

```
use shapefile::{Point, Polyline};
let points = vec![
    Point::new(1.0, 1.0),
    Point::new(2.0, 2.0),
];
let poly = Polyline::new(points);
```

If I print poly the "result" is:

```
GenericPolyline { bbox: GenericBBox { max: Point { x: 2.0, y: 2.0 }, min: Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 } }, parts: [[Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 }, Point { x: 2.0, y: 2.0 }]] }
```

I'm looking for a code to get this "result" and extract the x and y coordinates.

Comment: To read the shape file I use: `let shapes = shapefile::read("INFILL_13.shp").unwrap();` `let multilines = convert_shapes_to_vec_of::<Polyline>(shapes);`

Comment: Check out https://lib.rs/search?q=shapefile for crates that can parse shapefiles.

Answer (score 0):

In the [API documentation](https://docs.rs/shapefile/0.2.0/shapefile/reader/index.html) it says:

> If you know beforehand the exact type that the .shp file is made of,
> you can use the different *_as::() functions.:
>
> - read_as To read all the shapes as the specified type iter_shapes_as To
> - iterate over the shapes as shapes of the specified type
> - iter_shapes_and_records_as To iterate over both the shapes and records

So, you could do this:

```
let reader = shapefile::Reader::from_path("yourfile").unwrap();
let polylines = reader.read_as::<shapefile::Polyline>().unwrap();
```

Note that `read_as` returns a `Result` - one of the errors that can occur is if the file contains something other than polylines, so `unwrap` should be replaced with some proper error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to get only the x and y from Polyline shape files was:

```
let reader = Reader::from_path("INFILL_13.shp").unwrap();
for result in reader.iter_shapes_and_records_as::<Polyline>().unwrap() {
        let (shape, _record) = result.unwrap();
        for vpoints in shape.into_inner() {
            let mut Ss = String::new();
            for ponto in vpoints {
                let s1: String = ponto.x.to_string();
                let s2: String = ponto.y.to_string();
                Ss.push_str(&s1);
                Ss.push_str(",");
                Ss.push_str(&s2);
            }
            println!("{}", Ss);
        }
    }
```

The printed string Ss:

```
433403.6336002172,9548194.73184583449320.9987682806,9548289.982036332
433578.2589494678,9545958.998207698447687.92377904576,9545934.337120913
432939.3578235788,9542948.50823259443405.9999662347,9542971.00001528
439195.75016969733,9555649.486134548435244.52425377554,9538460.087277636
```

If anyone has an idea for a more elegant code, thank you.